# Trigger Wistia popover when clicking on an Elementor button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, popover, elementor, wistia

On an Elementor website https://beyond-short.com/ we have the following Wistia video popover code in an HTML widget:

```
<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/cnox3htqqb.jsonp" async></script><script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script><span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_cnox3htqqb popover=true popoverContent=link videoFoam=false" style="display:inline-block;height:63;position:relative;width:150"><a href="#">This is my popover!</a></span>
```

At the moment, the only way to trigger this popover is by clicking their link "This is my popover!" (below the banner). However, we don't want to use this link: we need to use an Elementor button or an image to trigger this popover.

Is there a way to associate a click on any Elementor element (button, menu link, or image) to trigger a click on this specific popover code from Wistia?

Any help would be extremely helpful as we're planning to repeat this process for several videos. Many thanks.

[Most of the info we could find online was to give the Elementor button an ID, then use a script that would "listen" to a click on that button and trigger the Wistia popover.]